# Visualizing bag files using d3.js

Tags: ros, visualization, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wonder if there is any previous work for visualizing bag files using d3.js. I know I can convert them to csv but even in that case they differ somewhat from the normal csv files. Any hint is really appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215087/visualizing-bag-files-using-d3.js/) by [lamiastella](https://answers.ros.org/users/23430/lamiastella/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could publish the contents of the bag using `rosbridge`:

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite

And then use `roslibjs` to interface it with `d3.js`:

http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs

If you want the data in a different flat format, you could use the rosbag API C++/Python to access the bag and then write it out to something else:

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lamiastella](https://answers.ros.org/users/23430/lamiastella/) on 2015-08-04**:
Hi @William can you please provide more details like the commands I should run in terminal? I am new to ROS and find this answer very high-level for me. Is there also a similar work of visualizing bag files using d3.js you can link me to? I've been googling but it was unsuccessful

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-08-04**:
I don't have time to walk you through it, but I'd recommend following the tutorials for rosbridge and/or roslibjs. I'm not aware of any out-of-the-box integration between d3.js and ROS. You're going to have to do some legwork and figure out what has already been done and what still needs to be done.